# Outdated Version of jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I have a plugin in wordpress (easy-fancy-box), which I think is adding this in my wp header.  `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.6.4'></script>`

This version is outdated and is preventing me from using newer versions of jquery, (if i add version 1.8 of jquery, then the fancy box plugin fails. Is there a way to update the version which easy-fancy-box uses?

I have tried searching for this in all the plugin files, but cannot locate where it is on order to change it to the newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it is not you or another plugin that is adding the jQuery?

I just had a look at the plugin you linked to, and it just calls the jQuery you registered to in WordPress.

Example line 402 in `easy-fancybox.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.fancybox', plugins_url(FANCYBOX_SUBDIR.'/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-'.FANCYBOX_VERSION.'.pack.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), FANCYBOX_VERSION);
```

jQuery is loaded as a dependency in that.

Look in your theme if you deregistered jQuery (using `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` )and registered it again to use Google's CDN.

Comment: thank you. I cannot find jquery version 1.6.4 in any of my wordpress files? is there perhaps a specific way for me to find this plugin which is causing this?

Comment: It is not a file. Look for the string `1.6.4` in your functions.php. Deactivate your plugins to be sure it's not another plugin that is messing with that.

Comment: YES ! I found it: `function thethe_image_slider_head_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.6.4');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   
 wp_enqueue_script('slider-ui', THETHE_IMAGE_SLIDER_URL.'style/js/thethe-image-slider.js', array('jquery'));
}`

Comment: remove the first two lines: `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.6.4');`

Comment: RRikesh - Thank you Thank you !! Fantastic.  no 1.6 version appearing in console anymore, and plugin is still working :)  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [Wordpress will load the latest version of JQuery anyway](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/), so you will probably be better of just removing the outdated version completely, rather than updating.

Secondly, providing that JQuery was enqueued in the recommend fashion, you can *dequeue* it using WP's `wp_dequeue_script` function, which you can [read about here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) You will need to know the *handle* that was assigned the script when it was originally enqueued in order to remove it.

The catch here is I'm not sure if Easy Fancy box is the plugin you should be looking at; I've had a quick scan through its files and I couldn't spot any instances of it enqueueing JQuery. So your suspect may be a different plugin. Look through your other plugins and keep an eye out for any instances of `wp_register_script` that point to V1.6.4 of JQuery. Once you have located the culprit, you can either comment out the relevant `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` lines, **which I wouldn't recommend,** *or* you can use the `wp_dequeue_script` and `wp_deregister_script` functions in your own `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thank you Dre.  I don't seem to find anywhere where dequeue was used? I will take a deeper look to try to find it. thank you

Comment: To clarify; you would use the *dequeue* function to *remove* the script. What you will need to *look* for is a `wp_register_script` or `wp_enqueue_script` function; the register function is used to first register the details of the script, such as location, version number as well as a *handle* to identify it. The enqueue function is the one that *actually* adds the script to the page, and it will use the handle* specified earlier on in the register function. Typically these two functions will appear very close to each other.